# TextBlock accepting only digits in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am creating an app in which I don't want alphabets or special characters to be used by the user except numbers(digits). The user can only enter digits ... if the user entered alphabets or special characters, then it will show an error message ... I have found the solution for the "null part" i.e.

```
if (uservalue == "" )
  textblock.text = "Sorry! enter digit please"
else
  textblock.text=y.toString();
```

If the user just press the "click me" button without entering the digit in the textbox, then this message "Sorry! enter digit please" appears in the textblock. I am wondering how can I fix the problem for alphabets and special characters?

Comment: You should edit your title. If you have a meaningful title, more people will read and answer your questions.

Answer (score 11):

You can change the keyboard of the phone, to display only digits, by adding the following in your TextBox:

```
<TextBox .... InputScope="Digits" ....>
```

This will still add the '.' key in the keyboard. To prevent users from typing it you add the KeyUp event to the TextBox and do the following:

```
private void KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    if (txt.Text.Contains('.'))
    {
        txt.Text = txt.Text.Replace(".", "");
        txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: The KeyUp event can be improved: just check if the `e.KeyCode` is the one for the "." and if so, make `e.Handled = true`

Comment: And what will happen when the user's region changes? Won't the '.' become a ',' ? Seems like Char.IsDigit should still be used regardless.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I'm not sure what will happen to the keyboard in a different region. If it changes, then a mix of defining the InputScope to Digits and validating on KeyUp for IsDigit is the best solution. I have to check that. Thanks Willmel.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method:

```
int digit;
if (!int.TryParse(uservalue, out digit))
{
    textblock.text = "Sorry! enter digit please";
}
else
{
    textblock.text = digit.toString();
}
```

This assumes that the user is supposed to enter a valid 32 bit integer. If you need to handle larger values where a very large amount of digits could be entered you could use the following regular expression `\d+` to validate the input:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(uservalue, @"\d+"))
{
    textblock.text = "Sorry! enter digit please";
}
else
{
    textblock.text = uservalue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TextBox` and set `TextBox.InputScope=Number` in your xaml. [InputScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.inputscope%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try this definitely it will work declare h and k as integer variables.textbox allows only numbers

```
private void txt3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int h = 58; h <= 127; h++)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == h)             //58 to 127 is alphabets tat will be         blocked
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }

        for(int k=32;k<=47;k++)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == k)              //32 to 47 are special characters tat will 
            {                                  be blocked
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Rithc Melton said, here is a list of all inputscope options

[Input scope list and tutorial](http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/07/06/WP7-InputScope.aspx)